# Wow slider and fancybox (lightbox) won't work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi, my FancybBox code works but then I start adding wowslider code then only the wowslider works properly. How do I solve this?

Here is the link to the page:
http://makaticitycondo.com/execstud_greenbelthamilton.html

If you click on Inquire Now button, a lightbox iframe is supposed to appear. But instead redirects it to a new page.

How can we solve this?

Comment: Can you put some code?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit do you need the jquery codes or should I just send the whole html code?

Comment: Ya may be fiddle would be easy http://jsbin.com/

Comment: @dholakiyaankit http://jsbin.com/OmEnOlaP/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

In link specify the attribute  `data-fancybox-type="iframe"`

Refer the [link](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe"  href="inqsend_ghes.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image2','','images/inquire.png',1)"><img src="http://makaticitycondo.com/images/inquired.png" name="Image2" width="204" height="120" border="0" id="Image2"></a>
```

Comment: I'm using the fancybox older version tho. Tried changing and it still wasn't able to work.

Comment: You used two jquery versions lastest and  other for wow silder. try to keep one jquery.